# data matrix function

Tags: function, matlab, math

I defined such a function as M-file M(t,Z,X,Y,p1,p2,p3,k,l). Here p1,p2,p3 are given parameters, X and Y are Grid inputs and Z=Z(X,Y,K,L). If I ask Matlab for example the output for t=3,k=4,l=5 then M(3,Z,X,Y,p1,p2,p3,4,5), I get a significant output.My Problem is I can't do the same thing for a data matrix like that:

```
t=[2 3 4]';
k=[3 4 5]';
l=[2 3 4]';
M(t,Z,X,Y,p1,p2,p3,k,l)
```

It is possible to the it in a for loop, but I need to leave it as a function using it in another function. Could you please help me?

Comment: How do you expect us to debug your function (the one you call M) without showing us its implementation ?  And what are 'kk' and 'll' doing here, they are irrelevant.

Comment: @High Performance Mark You are right:) But I don't want to bother anybody with my whole problem. I only want to ask whether it is possible to see the reason of this trouble? Thank you for your respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you feed a Matlab function a matrix, it doesn't go through and evaluate it point-by-point.  It uses the whole matrix as the input.  For some functions, this result may be identical, for example:

```
function f = y2(x)
f = y.^2;
end
```

Will product y^2 for a single-valued input, or if you input a vector, say y=[1, 2, 3] you will get the single-valued function outputs [1, 4, 9], but only because the function was written that way.  Alternatively, if your function was written:

```
function f = y2(x)
f = y^2;
end
```

You will get the same output for single-valued inputs, however, if you input a vector, it will attempt to do matrix multiplication, and thus will produce an error if y is not square.

You need to re-write your function so it produces the element-by-element evaluation you want.  The naive way to do it would be to define another function:

```
function fvec = Mvec(...)
[n k] = size(t)
fvec = zeros(n,k)
for i=1:n
    for j = 1:k
        fvec(i,j) = M(t(i,j),...)
    end
end
end
```

That will work, but is generally considered to be bad Matlab code, because, if written correctly, you should be able to replace those nested for loops with matrix operations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed answer! I exactly want to ask this.